# There is an error while uploading the file

Tags: point-of-sale

insert or update on table "item"\ violates foreign key constraint[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoYiC.png)

There is an error while updating the item on the environment of the pos

POS environment is showing the error when the file is being uploaded

Query Failed Error